# In what way does Spectre have "weak" liveness?

Tags: protocol, consensus, terminology

In his article [The Spectre Protocol](https://medium.com/@avivzohar/the-spectre-protocol-7dbbebb707b5), Aviv Zohar, one of Spectre's authors, mentions that **Spectre** has **weak liveness**.
Why does he mention that Spectre has **"weak"** liveness, and how would **"strong liveness"** differ from that?

Comment: @KappaDev I think research about better consensus algorithms is very relevant, even if not applicable in the short term. And even if not, this is just a question about the definition of terminology in consensus systems in general.

Answer (score 1):

[The paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/1159.pdf) explains this:

> The  “weakness”  of  the  Liveness  property  corresponds  to  the 
>   fact  that  we  do  not  guarantee (though  it  is  still  hard  for 
>   an  attacker  to  prevent)  a  resolution  in  case  conflicting 
>   transactions were published soon one after the other. Contrast this to
>   traditional consensus protocols, where all conflicts are required to be
>   decided in finite time, a property usually referred to as
>   Liveness. Observe, however, that an honest user of the system will
>   never publish conflicting transactions,and will transfer money only
>   after he robustly accepted the original funds (the inputs)
>   himself; payments of honest users are thus guaranteed to meet the
>   conditions formalized in Weak Liveness, and  to  be  robustly 
>   accepted.  On  the  other  hand,  an  attacker  trying  to  defraud 
>   must  keep  his attack secret before publishing the conflict, until the
>   victim robustly accepts; but then the victim is  guaranteed  that 
>   w.h.p.  his  transaction  will  not  be  reversed.  Therefore,  these 
>   two  properties together  ensure  that  payments  of  honest  users 
>   will  be  robustly  accepted  in  constant  expected time, and that
>   they remain robustly accepted forever, w.h.p.